# How to start external tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, maven

I have project and I use maven to to build project:

```
mvn clean install
```

also I've a tomcat 6 with setted external web module. so after maven I just stats tomcat and all work good.

But I want to do these two things (mvn-clean-install, start-tomcat) just by one click.
How I can start tomcat via maven? But I relly do no need to deploy project on tomcat...because  tomcat already "know" where my project exist.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this plugin : [Maven-Tomcat-Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html)

Comment: and what? neighter tomcat:start nor tomcat:run are not suitable for me. Do you read my question?

Comment: you cannot start tomcat with maven. You can do it by using an ant script and the maven-ant-plugin